# How to get path to python file running through open with

Tags: python, file, system

I can't seem to access the file-path I used "open-with" on

I'm creating my own text-editor that can open files, both through a open-tab(working) and by just opening a .txt file, using my .exe file converted from the script

I've tried a lot of different ways to access the file, but nothing seems to work

```py
try:
    fileName = str(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    with open(fileName) as _file:
        contentText.insert(1.0, _file.read())
    onContentChanged()
    root.title(os.path.basename(fileName) + " - Footprint Editor")
except:
    root.title("Untitled - Footprint Editor")
```

I try to get fileName to be equal to the path to the file I used "open with"
when .py file is converted to a .exe

Answer (score 0):

Use `_file.name` to get the path to the file you opened

```py
with open(fileName) as _file:
        print(f.name)
```

But if you want to see path while outside the `with open` you may have to use just `open` instead of `with open`

```py
_file=open(fileName)
# Do some stuff if you want here
print(_file.name)
```

Comment: This works for me to load new files, but not the initial file that I use open-with on for some weird reason, I think it might be because `fileName` is set to `None` earlier on, should I change that and only put the `None` in the except?

Comment: seems like it didn't work with removing the `fileName = None` at the start, so it seems like you would need some module or something like that.

Comment: I don't get it, Are you trying to find the path of the file you're currently running in or the path of the file you opened using `with open` or?

Comment: I'm sorry!! I'm trying to get the program to access the path to the file I opened using `open-with`

Comment: Do you have any sort of idea how I could fix that?

Comment: By using `with open` or open you're giving python access to the file, If you want it to be able to edit the file you can add `w`(write) or `r+`(Read and more)
Something like `with open("fileName", "r+")  as f`
If you want more info you could search on how to edit or write to a file

Comment: Ok, thank you! But the thing is, I'm trying to get the `fileName` to the file I use `open-with` on the windows desktop, or somewhere else. 

Since I want the program to be able to open a file on my desktop just by clicking on the file, without anything open, and then make it open my program and read the contents of the file